# How to exclude a compiled class which are located inside a jar

Tags: java, android, jar, gradle

I am building an apk using gradle which includes multiple jars. Some of these jars have same classes, which is causing the conflict during build and giving error: duplicate entry of class.

So, how do i exclude *.class from library in this construction?

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/myLibrary.jar')
}
```

For example, I want to exclude several classes from myLibrary.jar. I do not want to convert some *.class to dex format. How to prevent it?

Comment: Why not put the classes in separate packages (as should be)? That way there shouldn't be any conflicts and no need to remove either.

Comment: Try ProGuard: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html